# Script to join columns

Tags: linux, bash, grep, yum

I have two files:

The output of `yum list installed` which is now yum_installed and `yum list updates` now as yum_updates

What I need is to basically join the two files somehow but ONLY based on the packages that need to be updated. Lets say my 'yum_installed' file contains theoretically 6 packages:

```
openssh-clients.i386                  4.3p2-82.el5                     installed
openssh-server.i386                   4.3p2-82.el5                     installed
openssl.i686                          0.9.8e-22.el5_8.4                installed
oprofile.i386                         0.9.4-20.el5                     installed
orca.i386                             1.0.0-5.el5                      installed
pam.i386                              0.99.6.2-12.el5                  installed
```

My yum_updates lets say only contains these packages but if you notice, only the openssl needs to be updated so that is 1 package.

```
ntp.i386                             4.2.2p1-17.el5.centos               updates
openldap.i386                        2.3.43-28.el5_10                    updates
openssl.i686                         0.9.8e-27.el5_10.4                  updates
pcre.i386                            6.6-9.el5                           base   
perl.i386                            4:5.8.8-41.el5                      base   
pidgin.i386                          2.6.6-32.el5                        updates
```

What I want to do is basically just have the package in this case, the openssl and NEXT to it, the current and then the updated versions. My yum_installed file is long and has packages that don't need to be updated. I don't care about those.

The FINAL OUTPUT should look like this (a space delimited line is fine but here I am using pipes to separate the output.)

```
openssl.i686 | 0.9.8e-22.el5_8.4 | 0.9.8e-22.el5_8.4
```

Comment: I think you'll need `yum check-update` or `yum list updates`.

Comment: Yeah, `yum check-update` is what you're looking for.

Comment: I know about that command but it does not help since I cannot do a comparison. I basically need to show a comparison between what is current and what is to be updated. Old package vs new package on the same line. Thats my bottom line objective

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an approach:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$2; next} $1 in a && a[$1]!=$2 {print $1, a[$1], $2}' OFS="\t" inst upd
openssl.i686    0.9.8e-22.el5_8.4   0.9.8e-27.el5_10.4
```

It loops through `installed` file and stores the pair `(package, version)` in the `a[]` array. Then it loops through the `updated` list and checks:

- if package is stored AND
- the version doesn't match the stored for `installed` THEN
- prints `package` + `installed` + `update`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the "join" command, that probably does what you want.